# How to know which /proc file is used to set the backlight?

Tags: linux, laptop, power-management, backlight

How to know which /proc file is used to set the backlight ?

`$ ls -1F /proc/acpi/` returns :

```
ac_adapter/
battery/
button/
event
wakeup
```

`xbacklight` works.

I use awesomeWM with Ubuntu 12.04, on a dell laptop. The keyboard backlight control touches don't work even though it worked well under Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them. Modern Linux kernels expose hardware settings through `/sys`, and backlight "devices" usually can be found at `/sys/class/backlight`, each having a `…/brightness` parameter that controls the brightness level.

Comment: Back when `/proc/` was the odd-sock drawer it was possible with [`/proc/acpi/video/$DEVICE/brightness`](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9278), that's deprecated since [2.6.23](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/2.6.23/older/patch-2.6.23-rc1-rt6) or thereabouts.